# Rollback option visible directly underneath my post when it was edited by others

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks

I wrote a post, and somebody edited it. I liked that edit, but now there's a quite prominent option to undo that edit, titled "Rollback".

> [image]

When cliked, it shows a dialog:

> [image]

That looks quite ... nuclear. Why was this added, what is its purpose?

Comment: Maybe there's just not enough rollback wars on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Maybe it's been added to inform new 2k'ers of the "rollback" functionality? I don't know, I think it's a bad addition that will lead to more rollbacks and "testing" of this functionality.

Comment: [Apparently it was fixed so it now appears.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359477/capitalization-of-post-action-links-is-causing-multiple-rows-of-links#comment1199930_359477) I don't really know when it was introduced or if it ever showed up before it broke. Quoting Adam Lear: "*FWIW, the rollback button itself isn't new. But we had a bug that prevented it from showing up (and working) as intended. That fix is unrelated to the menu updates.*"

Comment: @VLAZ _"the rollback button itself isn't new"_ - I've never seen it, and I'm pretty sure I would've.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm just repeating what I saw. I cannot attest for its truthfulness. I've not seen any information about it other than this single comment from today.

Comment: @VLAZ I know you quoted Adam there. Seems my memory is off, I don't know for how many years this was broken, but the button was there "over a decade ago", see answer below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359398/rollback-button-appears-to-the-most-recent-edit-revision-item-if-its-a-rollback/359485#comment1199915_359485) [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359398/rollback-button-appears-to-the-most-recent-edit-revision-item-if-its-a-rollback/359485#comment1199917_359485) by [developer Brian Nickel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/235711/brian-nickel) on the Übermeta:

> [this rollback button in the post menu] was added over a decade ago and appears when you're the owner and the post was edited by someone else after you. [...] As for how it surfaced, I found out it wasn't being rendered when trying to test the new post menu code. My attempt to just completely delete it got overruled in code review, so here we are.

I don't like it being there as I think people aren't familiar with it and are going to start rollback wars, either intentionally or not, but as they said, here we are.

Comment: Yeah, this is really unfortunate. I cannot tell you how frequently I see auto "rollback war" flags being raised because some new user was unfamiliar with how edits work and rolled back an edit that was made to their post, seemingly just because they could, only to roll it back again (putting the edit back in place) a few minutes later because the edit was actually a major improvement. There is no need to make the rollback option more prominent. Having it in the edit history is good enough. You cannot even *decide* to roll back without *first* viewing the actual edit history...

Comment: There is a chat room dedicated to bots on SO. A bot there keeps track of [newly awarded 'Clean up' badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4/cleanup). This helps in keeping an eye out on incorrectly done rollbacks.

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65666089/revisions) is an example of this happening. (see rev 3)

Comment: @Yatin That is not really a good example, because that edit is objectively incorrect: it's code formatting only `gradle`, and not `gradle clean` (as that is the full command), and why isn't it giving the same treatment for the other commands in that list. It also added the `java` code format for something that is gradle log/error output, not Java code, etc.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for improving the edit. I am not a Java programmer so I just tried editing it as best as I could. :)

Comment: [Here is a better example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65705847/revisions) of someone who was obviously confused by the "rollback" link.

Comment: [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65728715/revisions) example. My point being, this button isn't really needed **here**. It can stay hidden under the edit section and out of curious and inexperienced hands, where it just causes problems.